# Retain the value of textbox when an error occurs in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

I am developing a webapp. In that app i have a page which have three search options based on id. If the ID is wrong i want to retain the id in search textbox and i want to show an error message. I tried that with

ModelAndView.addObject("id", value);

And this is working fine , **Now i want to know if there is a better way to do this because assume i have a big form and i want to retain the value of every field than it will be difficult using the above approch**. Please help!

**And i am using search by ID and Name both thats why i have try and catch blocks**

this is my jsp file

```
    html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
        <script>
            function redirectToSearchResult(textBoxId){
                window.location.href= document.getElementById(textBoxId).name+'.htm?'+'id='+document.getElementById(textBoxId).value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header"></div>

        <div id="searchByBuyer">
            <label id="E_B_I"><h2>Buyer Search<h2></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="S_B_B" class="text-box" name="searchByBuyer" value=${buyerId} ></input>
            <input type="button" id="BuyerSearch" class="btn-custom" value="search" onclick="redirectToSearchResult('S_B_B')"/>
        </div>

        <div id="searchByCategory">
            <label id="E_C_I"><h2>Category Search<h2></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="S_B_C" class="text-box" name="searchByCategory" value=${categoryId} ></input>
            <input type="button" id="CategorySearch" class="btn-custom" value="search" onclick="redirectToSearchResult('S_B_C')"/>
        </div>

        <div id="searchByArticle">
            <label id="E_A_I"><h2>Article Search<h2></label><br>
            <input type="text" id="S_B_I" class="text-box" name="searchByArticle" value=${articleId} ></input>
            <input type="button" id="ArticleSearch" class="btn-custom" value="search" onclick="redirectToSearchResult('S_B_I')"/><br>
        </div>

        <br>
        <label style="color:red; padding-left:45em; padding-top:15em"><h4>${error}</h4></label>
     </body>

</html>
```

And this my controller

`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class BuyerController {

    @Autowired
    private BuyerRepo buyerRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchByBuyer.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView searchFields(@RequestParam(value = "id") String buyerId) throws InvalidIdException {
        Buyer buyer = null;
        ModelAndView buyerSearch = new ModelAndView("buyerSearch");
        ModelAndView errorView = ErrorView.getErrorView("buyerId", buyerId, "Enter a valid Buyer id!");

        try {
            buyer = buyerRepo.getBuyer(Long.parseLong(buyerId));

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            buyer = buyerRepo.getBuyer(buyerId);
            if (buyer == null) return errorView;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            buyerSearch = errorView;
        }

        buyerSearch.addObject("buyer", buyer);
        return buyerSearch;
    }

}
```

`

This is the error and view class to create error view with parameters

`

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class ErrorView {

    public static ModelAndView getErrorView(String key, String value, String message) {
        ModelAndView errorView = new ModelAndView("index");
        errorView.addObject("error", message);
        errorView.addObject(key, value);
        return errorView;
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Spring has JSR 303-Bean-Validation support for web forms.
This build in way is much easyer to use than some own implementation.

You need:

- a command object that gets all the values from the form. Each fields can have JSR 303-Bean-Validation annotations to indicate the constaints you want to enforce
- you need a web controller method with (at least) two parameters: `@Valid` command object, `BindingResult` (The `BindingResult` must be THE parameter after the command object)
- in you web controller method you need to check the `BindingResult`, and if it has failure you need to render the form again
- in your form you need to use `form:errors` to show the errors (`form:errors` can also show the errors for an specific field)
- you need some spring configuration: `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (there is more possible but this should be enough for the begin)
- you need a JSR 303-Bean-Validation libary, for example: Hibernate Validator (this is not the Hibernate ORM)

**But an example explain it the best:**  http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/